# Difference between num.standby.replicas vs max.warmup.replicas

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am bit confused to understand the difference between ***num.standby.replicas*** and ***max.warmup.replicas***.
Both sound same to me as both are helping to reduce the time taken in getting a standby task and it's state store ready to be promoted as active while a consumer group rebalancing is happening.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`num.standbys` is a per-task setting applies for HA; if you lose a task, Kafka Streams migrates the standby task to the active task immediately.

For `max.warmup.replicas` is a "global" setting, and it only applies to the case where you are scaling out, adding a Kafka Streams instance with the same application-id.

In the scale-out scenario, with a `max.warmup.replicas=1`, Kafka Streams would "warm up" a single task A by starting A' on the new node, and when A' is up to the acceptable lag setting, task A will migrate to the new node (A' -> A) then the process will repeat for another task if you set `max.warmup.replicas=2`, then Kafka Streams will warmup two tasks A and B, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are very similar. As the documentation states, the warmup replicas are "extra standbys beyond the configured `num.standbys`." And, there are 2, by default.

Meanwhile, `num.standby.replicas=0`, by default